# Populating IEnumerable<MyType> using Linq gives error "The specified type member is not supported in LINQ to Entities."

Tags: linq, odata, ienumerable

I have a model in which some fields are directly mapped to database table and I expose it through Odata (v4). I created one unmapped property which is an IEnumerable and I map it runtime in my webapiconfig. My model looks like this

```
public class MyClass
{
public int ID {get;set;}
public string Name {get;set;}    
[NotMapped] 
[ForeignKey("MyType")]
public virtual IEnumerable<MyType> MyCollection { get { return context.MyCollection.AsQueryable(); } set { ;} }

}
```

Now when I run it and try to get results for the url
http://localhost/ODataService/MyClass(1)?$expand=MyCollection, it gives me an error saying 
            "message": "The specified type member 'Test' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported.

Can anyone point out how to populate the Ienumerable runtime using linq?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The error is saying your type doesn't map to some DB entity. I would guess `MyType` is a C# type with no db equivalent (seems you said that in the question). An `IEnumerable<MyType>` is perfectly fine but when you use it, it needs to be in the context of LINQ to Objects not LINQ to Entities or LINQ to SQL. If you want to populate an `IEnumerable<MyType>` at runtime the correct way of doing so would be like this;

```
  IEnumerable<MyType> myTypes = SomeCollectionFromMyDb.Select(x => new MyType { FieldOnMyType=x.ColumnA, OtherField=x.ColumnB });
```

Basically, you should just use `Select` on your LINQ to Entities collection to project your entities into instances of `MyType` *when* you need them.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your response. I tried this, but get the same error.
        [ForeignKey("MyTypeModel")]
       public virtual IEnumerable<MyType> MyCollection{ get { return context.MyCollection.Select(x => new MyType{ MyTypeFiield=x.Column}); } set { ;} }

Comment: @Maggi no, see in my example `myTypes` is a collection in the scope of some method. In your code it is a field on a class (which is supposed to represent a db entity, thus your problem) and you're doing that logic in it's getter. What I'm saying is rather than making it a field on `MyClass` which will not be allowed because it's not supported by LINQ to Entities, you need to use the logic in your getter at the location where you actually need the collection.

Comment: Hi, I totally get what you are suggesting and I wrote a new wrapper which populates my collection by projecting myclass as following:                

                               select new MyClass
                               {                            
                                   ID = context.PropertyID,
                                   MyCollection= context.SomeCollection
                               }; The only problem is now I get "The entity or complex type MyClass cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query"

Comment: Which means MyClass cannot be projected using new keyword since it is mapped from database. The solution works perfectly when I make a copy of MyClass as MyClassPseudo and project that class. But I want to avoid making a copy of MyClass which has 1000 attributes and doesn't seem to be an elegant solution even if I use an anonymous type.

Comment: @Maggi what if MyClassPseudo inherits from MyClass rather than just copying it? Unfortunately I don't think you have any options here for what you want to do. Either keep the stuff as entities or convert them over to objects but either way you're going to have to take one of those trade offs.

Comment: Inheritance leads to the same error. But thanks for exploring options. For what I need, I need to convert my entites to objects only to accommodate my collections. In the absence of collections I would have just left my entites as is.

Answer (score 0):

So, I resolved this issue by just removing ForeignKey and changing Ienumerable to IList. OdataV4 figures out relationships based on Primary key, so if MyType has a key defined, it establishes a relationship.

```
public class MyClass
{
[Key]
public int ID {get;set;}
public string Name {get;set;}    
public virtual IList<MyType> MyCollection { get ; } set { ;} }
}
```